Find missing dates in another table with different where criteria
I have multiple volatile tables where the structure is like this
Table 1
Ref#     criteria.   Date
abc123.   Yellow.    10/02/1990
abc123.   Yellow.    11/02/1990
abc123.   Yellow.    08/02/1990

Table 2
Ref#.    Criteria.   Date
abc123.   Pink.      10/02/1990
abc123.   Pink.      11/02/1990
abc123.   Pink.      08/02/1990
abc123.   Pink.      05/02/1990

I want to write a query that matches the ref# but finds from the other table/s the date that doesn't exist in another table under the different where criteria eg yellow vs pink
I tried a query where I did a left and inner joins join on
A.Ref#=b.ref# and a.date<>b.date
But it was only finding rows where there didn't match. I tried not exists too but that also didn't work how I'd like.
Pretty much I just wanna pull out the single date that doesn't exist from the other table where the ref# still matches

Use a Left Join:
SELECT 
    [Table 2].[Ref#], 
    [Table 2].Date
FROM 
    [Table 2] 
LEFT JOIN 
    [Table 1] 
    ON ([Table 2].Date = [Table 1].Date) AND ([Table 2].[Ref#] = [Table 1].[Ref#])
WHERE 
    [Table 1].Date Is Null

Result:

